# I want to run the Visual DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe installer using CMD, but the CMD runs without executing the command

Tags: c#, cmd, command-line, accessibility, admin

I tried running my software as an admin and checked if it was a permission issue, but to no avail.

```
string command = "cd \"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\VSI\\DisableOutOfProcBuild\" && DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe";
 Process process1 = new Process();
 process1.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
 process1.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
      

 process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 process1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true; // Activer la redirection de la sortie d'erreur
 process1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
 process1.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";


  process1.Start();
 process1.BeginOutputReadLine();
 process1.BeginErrorReadLine();
 process1.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Please read the Microsoft documentation for the [Process Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process) which is a .NET wrapper class for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) called also by `cmd.exe` for running an executable with a proper filled out [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure.

Comment: There is absolutely no need calling with `Process` class `CreateProcess` for running `cmd.exe` which calls also `CreateProcess` for running `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild\DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe`. The executable can be run directly from within C# coded application with usage of the `Process` class giving the C# coded application full control on how this executable is run which is not possible on using unnecessarily `cmd.exe` for program execution.

Comment: `process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\VSI\\DisableOutOfProcBuild";` could be used for passing this directory path via function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory` to `CreateProcess` if it is really necessary that the current directory is the directory of `DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe`. I doubt that this is necessary as Microsoft executables usually work independent on which directory is the current directory on using the fully qualified file name for starting the executable.

Answer (score 0):

In the command string put /C first

> **/C** cd \C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\DisableOutOfProcBuild\ && DisableOutOfProcBuild.exe

Comment: It runs successfully, thank you.